# Using Composer to install a package

Tags: php, api, composer-php

I'm trying to install a package I found on GitHub.
It's using composer which I've never used before. I am familiar to PHP however.

I installed composer via the executable and the directory was set to my PHP folder in my xampp server.

Im trying to install this package:
https://github.com/zahav/zahav-laravel

When I type

```
 php composer require "zahav/zahav-laravel"
```

I get this error on my CMD.

```
dir=$(cd "${0%[/\\]*}" > /dev/null; pwd)
if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ]; then
    case $(which php) in
        $(readlink -n /proc/cygdrive)/*)
            # We are in Cygwin using Windows php, so the path must be translated
            dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
            ;;
    esac
fi
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Please share more details - the given code does not look like an error to me

Answer (score 0):

Use composer without php, i.e. `composer require "zahav/zahav-laravel"`